# Are All Orthogonal Matrices Conformal Mappings?

Tags: linear-algebra

I ran into an interesting result which showed that if $A$ is an orthogonal matrix then $$\left\vert\left\vert Ax \right\vert\right\vert = \left\vert\left\vert x \right\vert\right\vert$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

So now I am wondering if all orthogonal mappings are also conformal mappings.

Answer (score 3):

okay nevermind,

I just saw this [paper](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~rauch/555/Conformal_Matrices.pdf)

**EDIT**

Okay,

Now that I have more time, I will explain:

A conformal matrix $M = R \cdot O$ where $R$ is positive definite and $O$ is orthogonal.

The paper continues on:

If $M$ is an invertible matrix then the image by $M$ of the
unit sphere is an ellipse whose principal axes have length $2\cdot \lambda_j$ where the $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of $R$ in the polar decomposition $M = R\cdot O$. The direction of the axes are the corresponding eigendirections.

The image is a sphere if an only if $R = cI$ with $c > 0$ if and only if
$M^t \cdot M = c^2\cdot I$.